# Dynamic traceability view of multiple level linked Modules in DOORS V9.6

Tags: ibm-doors, traceability

I have four modules A, B, C and D where in each module is linked i.e., A -> B -> C -> D. The lower level module has only reference to next higer level module. So i cannot draw links from D to B for example. My aim is to be able to see a top down traceability view in Module A from all the 3 modules (B, C & D). Better described, i should be able to see a particular attribute from each Module B, C & D in Module A to create a traceability matrix in A.

i tried the following method:

Using Wizard Analysis tool, generate the reference attribute from higher level module and copy it into a text attribute in low level module so that links can be drawn directly from C and D modules to A. But this will not make the job dynamic and everytime there is an update in middle level modules, i will have to repeat this step.

IBM Rational DOORS V9.6 is used for this purpose. Any suggestions/Ideas using DXL scripting are also welcome. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What you describe sounds like the recursive analysis of out links using the analysis wizard in Module A. In it, you can specify that you want to see attributes from e.g. 3 levels of recursion. You will get 3 columns, one for each depth (B, C, D). Is this what you needed or is there a reason why you cannot use it?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below

1. Keep A, B, C, D modules opened
2. Go to Analysis -> Wizard
3. Select Outlinks
4. Select **All open modules**
5. Select **All modules** for (Select linkmoule)
6. Select the attributes you want to display (For Ex: Object Text)
7. Put 4 for (Specify depth of analysis). Check Recursive Analysis and Multiple columns
8. Finish

All attributes you selected get displayed in 4 columns. I tested its working.

Comment: What if there are multiple modules at B, C and D levels with different linkmodules. For example, A is linked to 10 Modules at B level, and each of these 10 modules at B level are linked to C level modules and so on. In this case the recursive analysis was not helpful

Comment: In that case select 10 modules at each level in wizard in place of step 4) above